# How to change where you fall

Tags: scripting, game-engine, logic-bricks

i'm trying to make a gravity game where you can use keys to change the direction you fall, solving puzzles etc. so how do i change the direction you fall entirely?

Comment: Look at this [blenderartists thread](https://blenderartists.org/t/changing-gravity-direction-in-bge/589436) and [allitebooks](http://www.allitebooks.org/).

Comment: can you put something that better explains your question an image of what you want to do or a drawing, because I do not understand if what you want is to change the sense of the force of gravity or if you want to walk on the walls or the one that does not stand out and below for example to walk in a bucket on all sides without falling into the void